# Is it possible to have if else in http request in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.fetch =function()
                        {
                        $http(req)
                                .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                                        if(status==0)
                                        {
                                            console.log(data);
                                            console.log(status);

                                        else{
                                .error(function(response,status,headers,config) {

                console.log("error");
                console.log(headers);
                console.log(fd);
            });
```

What i mean is if status is 0 i would like to print that status is zero  else it comes to the error block and prints a alert msg.I tried like above but unable to correct the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to have if/else blocks in JavaScript.  You do, however, need to close any open brackets you create and maintain the structure of any functions you write.  Let's start with the HTTP call:

```
$http(req)
  .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
    // do this on success
  })
  .error(function(response,status,headers,config) {
    // do this on error
  });
```

What you were trying to do was mix an if/else block with the structure of these functions.  That, of course, won't work.  The JavaScript interpreter would have no idea how to make sense of that.  But *within* any given function, you can certainly have an if/else block.

For example, if within a successful operation you may receive different response content and wish to handle it differently, you'd do that entirely within the `success` callback:

```
$http(req)
  .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
    if (status == 0) {
      // do one thing
    } else {
      // do another thing
    }
  })
  .error(function(response,status,headers,config) {
    // do this on error
  });
```

Comment: I'm having a pretty hard time finding what [status code 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) actually means and how it will enter the success block.

Comment: @skubski: Completely agreed.  I really only used it as a demonstration because it was the conditional check made in the original question.  Whatever condition the code needs to check would be fine.  I've only ever seen a 0 in cases where I was debugging and shut down the server application mid-request, leaving the browser with no meaningful response.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible, because the `success` and `error` callbacks are called by angular by considering the `status` of the `$http` request, if the `status` is `200` it will call the success callback, otherwise it will call the `error` callback.

```
$http(req)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // this will call when there is no error on `$http` request.
    }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        // this will call when there is error on `$http` request.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by put an external method for error. This method will be call on your error and on your succes if status is 0.

```
$scope.error = function(response,status,headers,config){
     console.log("error");
     console.log(headers);
     console.log(fd);
}
$scope.fetch =function(){
      $http(req).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                     if(status==0){
                          console.log(data);
                          console.log(status);
                     }else{
                          $scope.error(data,status,headers,config);
                     }
                 .error($scope.error(response,status,headers,config));
```